# Rotate GMSMarker in iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps

I want to rotate GMSMarker like a globe. I have tried to use Rotate animation code but they all need UIImageView but in case of GMSMarker I don't have UIImageView container. Also, I am not sure can we do this

Please suggest.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678575/gmsmarker-opacity-animation-not-repeating see this for custom animation on gms marker

Comment: that does not help me I need 3D rotation on map marker

Answer (score 2):

The `GMSMarker` is a `NSObject`, not an `UIView`. So you can not use `UIView.aniamteWithDuration()` for it.

Also, you can only apply `CATransform3D` to `UIView`, so you can not do `marker.layer.transform = rotationTransform` either.

However, the `GMSMarker` has an UIImage property called `icon`. You can use it as a workaround by changing the size of the `icon` property of your `GMSMarker`.

Sample code:

```
  let originalImage = UIImage(named: "markerIcon")

  delay(seconds: 0.05) { () -> () in
      marker.icon = self.newImageWithWidth(originalImage!, width: originalImage!.size.width/2, height: originalImage!.size.height)
      delay(seconds: 0.05, { () -> () in
          marker.icon = self.newImageWithWidth(originalImage!, width: 0.1, height: originalImage!.size.height)
          delay(seconds: 0.05, { () -> () in
              marker.icon = self.newImageWithWidth(originalImage!, width: originalImage!.size.width/2, height: originalImage!.size.height)
              delay(seconds: 0.05, { () -> () in
                  marker.icon = self.newImageWithWidth(originalImage!, width: originalImage!.size.width, height: originalImage!.size.height)
               })
           })
       })
   }
```

The code above change the `width` the marker icon every 0.05 second, from half to 0.1, then back to half and full size.

[image]

Sample code about changing size of UIImage:

```
 func newImageWithWidth(image: UIImage, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) -> UIImage{
        let imageSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize)

        let imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)
        image.drawInRect(imageRect)

        let resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return resizedImage
    }
```

You can find the full source code in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/ziyang0621/c8ee4b9981d1eb1343ff).